# MySQL Error Code: 1238. Variable 'ft_min_word_len' is a read only variable

Tags: mysql

How do I change the ft_min_word_len variable in mysql?
I tried to run the command `set ft_min_word_len = 3;` but It returns me the following error:
*Error Code: 1238. Variable 'ft_min_word_len' is a read only variable*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In debian/ubuntu OS you can change the value of `ft_min_word_len` by updating the `my.cnf` file
The location of the file is usually under

`/etc/mysql`

So go to the above folder and type

`sudo vi my.cnf`

Then in the file check for the block `[mysqld]` and see if the variable is already there if not then just add the line

`ft_min_word_len = 3`

Save it and and restart mysql

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

or

`sudo service mysql restart`

If you already had the full text indexes on a table before doing the above operation, after above changes drop the indexes and rebuit or you can do a repair the table from mysql terminal something as

`repair table table_name quick`

Answer (score 1):

put in my.cnf

```
[mysqld] 
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

Comment: I have added above line in wampp my.ini file in windows and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Only `Dynamic Variable` can be changed while MySQL is running. `ft_min_word_len` is not a dynamic variable. You can see MySQL Manaual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)

So you can change it's value as other answerer mentioned.

Please note that if there are tables which already has fulltext index, they need to be rebuilt to affect `ft_min_word_len` changed.